# How to get an array to check in the in_array function? See description Below

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am fetching the data using mysql_fetch_array like :

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($select))
{
$tables[] =$row;
}
```

Now i need this $tables array as one dimensional array only, so that i can use it in

```
if(in_array($val['table_name'],$tables))
        { 
           //Some Code
        }
```

to check for whether the $val['table_name'] is in the $tables or not..
As for now I am getting $tables array as

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [TABLE_NAME] => jos_audittrail
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [TABLE_NAME] => jos_banner
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [TABLE_NAME] => jos_bannerclient
        )
..
..
..
..
}
```

But I need the $tables is form of..

```
Array
(
    [0] => jos_audittrail
    [TABLE_NAME] => jos_audittrail


    [1] => jos_banner
    [TABLE_NAME] => jos_banner

    [2] => jos_bannerclient
    [TABLE_NAME] => jos_bannerclient
..
..
..
}
```

**How can i get the above array after applying "while loop" to "$row"?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the array as you want it, you can do:

```
$tables = array();
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($select)) {
    $tables[$i++] =$row['TABLE_NAME'];
    $tables['TABLE_NAME'] =$row['TABLE_NAME'];
}
```

Comment: But I Just removed the "$tables['TABLE_NAME'] =$row['TABLE_NAME'];
" line..it was displayed in between the array..